# Как правильно задать tooltip в SVG с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, svg

Как правильно задать *tooltip* в SVG с помощью JS, если SVG добавляется через `<object>`, и элементы SVG  имеют только `id` и не имеют `<title>`?

```
    <div class="box-body">
        <center>
            <object id="idImageSVG" class="svgClass" type="image/svg+xml" data="./img/exoModel.svg">
                Your browser does not support SVG
            </object>
        </center>
    </div>

$(window).load(function ()
{
    g_SvgModel = document.getElementById("idImageSVG");
    var svgDoc = g_SvgModel.contentDocument;
    g_SvgDrive1 = svgDoc.getElementById("drive1");
}

function updateSysInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/dashboard/states',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.err) {
                setTimeout(updateSysInfo,1000);
            } else {
                if (g_SvgTooltipDrive1 != null)
                {
                    var tooltip = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'title');
                    tooltip.innerHTML = 'текст тул-типа';

                    g_SvgTooltipDrive1.setAttribute('textContent', '11111');
                }

                setTimeout(updateSysInfo,1000);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            notifyError(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Дайте пример SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <g>
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"/>
    <title>Его тул-тип</title>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Положить `title` в одну группу с элементом.

Если это надо делать через JS то создаёте `title` програмно

```
let tooltip = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'title');
tooltip.innerHTML = 'текст тул-типа';
```

И потом добавляете в группу к элементу.

**EDIT:**

Если `g_SvgDrive1` является группой то просто сделайте:

```
g_SvgDrive1.appendChild(tooltip);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как правильно добавить в группу к элементу?

Comment: <div class="box-body">
                <center>
                    <object id="idImageSVG" class="svgClass" type="image/svg+xml" data="./img/exoModel.svg">
                        Your browser does not support SVG
                    </object>
                </center>
            </div>

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо. И еще вопрос небольшой - css к tooltip как правильно подключить?

Comment: @Илья По моему это невозможно.

Comment: Т.е. это будет встроенный (базовый) стиль <title>?

Comment: Да. Можно сделать что то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703318/is-it-possible-to-enhance-the-default-appearance-of-svg-title-tooltip). Но там уже не `title` а просто группа которую показывают через CSS.